I have confusion between the concept of distance and displacement
I can't understand that why do we say that distance is a scaler quantity and displacement is a vector quantity?
Let me give some examples:
$1)$ Shyam is travelling from New Delhi to Mumbai. Now according to this example we can say that distance and displacement are same. Now can anyone explain me that for this example why displacement has direction and distance doesn't have direction? Here why distance doesn't have any direction? Both distance and displacement are same for this example.
According to me distance should also have direction for this case because since displacement has direction.
I can't understand that where I am wrong ?
Ex:$2)$ Shyam is travelling from New Delhi to Mumbai via Punjab. For this example we can easily say that distance $>$ displacement. The displacement here is from New Delhi to Mumbai. Whereas distance is from (New Delhi to Punjab) $+$ (Punjab to Mumbai).
Now I really can't understand that why do we generally say that displacement has direction and distance doesn't have direction ?
For the $2^{nd}$ example why distance doesn't have direction whereas displacement has direction ?
Finally what I am trying to say is that if displacement has direction then distance should also have direction. And if displacement doesn't have direction then distance should also not have direction.
Please clear my doubt.

You seem to conflate the idea of a vector (has direction) with the idea of its magnitude (does not have direction). Two distinct ideas. Each is useful in its own way.

Yes you are absolutely correct @Farcher. But I want to know that why distance doesn't have direction ? According to your answer, summation of displacements gives distance. Therefore distance should also have direction.

This question is similar to: Displacement vs. Distance. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

We define distance to be a "directionless" quantity and displacement to be a vector quantity because its useful to define them this way. Consider a round trip on a line between two points. At the end of the round trip, the distance traveled would be twice the distance between the two points, but the displacement zero. We define them differently because we use them to describe qualitatively different things.
In the first case you describe, the distance just happens to be the magnitude of the displacement, because none of the intermediate displacement vectors are getting "cancelled out", like in the second case. It may help to draw this phenomenon out on a paper with individual displacement vectors tracing out the journey.

Yes obviously. It is correct that the displacement in a round trip is always $0$. But can u explain me that if displacement is $0$ then how displacement can have direction ? @Hrithik Narayan

@DEBSANKARROY, the direction of the zero vector is undefined, but that does not prevent it from obeying all the same laws of vector algebra as every other vector. Zero is a special case. Every other vector has a well defined direction.

Shyam is travelling from New Delhi to Mumbai. Now according to this example we can say that distance and displacement are same.
If you look up New Delhi to Mumbai on the Internet you get two values:

aerial (straight line) route, $1148\,\rm km$ on bearing $203^\circ$, and

driving route, $1408\,\rm km$.


The difference is there because in the second case the journey is characterised by incremental displacements each with a magnitude and different direction, and the incremental magnitudes need to be added together to evaluate the distance travelled.
In the first case the directions of the incremental displacements does not change.

Using your own example, let's say that you're planning to fly from Delhi to Ludhiana (284km), and then from Ludhiana to Mumbai (1350km).
How far did you fly?
$$284+1350 = 1634\text{km}$$
That number is useful if you want to know how much time you will spend in the air, or how much fuel the airplane will need.
Now, let's say you plan to return directly home to Delhi. How far is that? It's approximately 1147km. That's 487km less than the 1634km that you travelled on your way to Mumbai. How is that possible?
Let's let $A$ be the vector which represents the displacement from Delhi to Ludhiana. Its magnitude, $|A|$, is 284km. The magnitude of a displacement vector corresponds to the distance travelled. Likewise, let $B$ be the vector representing the displacement from Ludhiana to Mumbai, and $|B|=1350$.
If you want to know the total distance that you travelled on the first part of your journey, that's the sum of the magnitudes of the vectors (the sum of the distances):
$$|A| + |B| = 1634$$
If we know both $A$ and $B$, we can calculate the displacement from Dehli directly to Mumbai. That's the vector sum of $A$ and $B$ (Let's name it $C$) and the distance that you will have to travel to return directly home is equal to the magnitude of that sum:
$$A+B=C$$
$$|A+B| = |C| = 1147km$$

So, you can see that there's two different ways of adding $A$ and $B$, two different reasons for adding $A$ to $B$, and they give two different answers.


But I want to know: why doesn't direction have direction?

Consider a ruler. It is a device that measures spatial separation or distance. The length of the ruler does not change no matter what direction we orientate it in. That is why distance or length does not have direction.
Sometimes, it is useful to use scalar quantities where direction is ignored. If we were to measure the displacement from Punjab to New Delhi as $+ X \ \text{km}$, then the displacement of New Delhi from Punjab would be $- X \ \text{km}$. If we want to calculate the fuel consumption, we would use fuel used divided by distance. If we used displacement, the fuel consumption on the trip from New Delhi to Punjab would be negative, which is, of course, nonsense.
If you were to drive from New Delhi to Punjab following a zig-zag route, the distance as measured by a ruler without consideration of vector direction might be $2X$. The fuel used would be twice as much as the fuel consumed when driving there in a straight line. The fuel consumption of the vehicle remains the same. However, if we were to measure the fuel consumption as fuel used divided by the vector displacement from New Delhi, we would get the wrong answer.
Alternatively, consider the gravitational force of a gravitational body with mass $M$ and a test particle with mass $m$. The force is proportional to $F = \dfrac{GMm}{R^2}$ and is dependent on the magnitude of $R$ and independent of direction because gravity acts equally in all directions.

See friend you are not wrong anywhere you just have confusion between vector and scalar quantities. let me clear it to you,
See displacement is just the direct path from 'New Delhi' to 'Mumbai'. In case of a direct path (Please think practically) we can say someone to go in 14' northeast direction or any direction right? this means I have specified a Direction to the person.
Now, In the distance, you never specify the direction right? If you have to go to Noida(For example) and your friend doesn't know about the place You will tell him it is near Delhi and 100 km (for example) from us. There is another example
You are telling Your friend where your home is from the park you tell him From here the 2nd lane right then left and so on. This shows that there are multiple directions now You can't specify it in one direction, so that's why Direction is only applicable to Displacement, not Distance.
Thank You,
If you still have questions please ask.

The reason is that is how the two quantities are defined. They are defined that way because we have situations - both in and out of physics as a scientific practice - where we want to either have or not have that added directional and "averaging" information. Like if Shyam just wants to know how long sie will take to travel from New Delhi to Mumbai, sie is not interested as much in the direction, just the distance (provided sie also knows the speed of hir preferred mode of transport). But if, say, one were building a network of communication towers to connect the two cities, one would obviously need the direction to understand how to aim the dishes so that the signal can be successfully routed from one to the other. Or if one is the pilot of a plane between them and not just a passenger, one would first need to aim the plane and that means knowing the direction.
(Note in my communication towers example, realistically terrain and other factors will likely mean we will need to consider several displacements, i.e. those between each tower and its successor. This is just an oversimplified illustrative example.)
Thus, to meet the needs of different contexts, we need two different measuring quantities.
As for the fact that the distance covered in your trip is greater than the size of the displacement when you go by way of Punjab, that's because the displacement is intended to describe your aggregate overall motion, and not the finer details of the motion. It's a "summary", if you will, of the result of your trip. It is intended to provide, and only provides, the minimal information needed to find the destination from the origin, which is both the direction and the straight-line distance between the two points. In the indirect motion case, the distance covered is greater because the arc length of the actual path covered is greater due to not being a straight line, since Punjab is westerly of New Delhi, IIRC, while Mumbai is far to the south, hence the former is not on the straight line between New Delhi and the latter.
Formally, let $P_1$ and $P_2$ be two points. Then we define displacement by
$$\Delta \mathbf{r} := P_2 - P_1.$$
This is an "affine operation". One way of conceptualizing Euclidean space is as what is called "affine space", which is, omitting some technical details, a point set together with an operation $-$ on pairs of points that is defined as specifying what the displacement between those points is in an associated vector space (here also equivalent to Euclidean space in a sense, but not always in the general case). By specifying the displacements between points, we can write out the geometry of the space.
The distance, however, is an arc length integral:
$$s := \int_{t=0}^{1} ds$$
where $ds$ is the arc length element, which can be thought of as the magnitude of an infinitesimal displacement along a path, which here we understand as a function $gamma$ of a parameter $t$ representing the "progress" along the trip (think the 0 and 1 as like "0% complete" and "100% complete"). Viz. informally,
$$ds := |\gamma(t + dt) - \gamma(t)|$$
which is equivalent to the more formally correct
$$ds = |\gamma'(t)|\ dt.$$
Note that the above subtraction is the displacement operation defined earlier, so yields a displacement vector from the points $\gamma(t + dt)$ and $\gamma(t)$, representing the tiny trip segment in moving from $\gamma(t)$ to its (fictitious, due to the continuous nature of a line/curve) immediate next successor, $\gamma(t + dt)$. If you want, you can imagine the distance as "walk the points along path $\gamma$, and add up the lengths of each and every little straight-line step you take". The integral does that addition, in the limit of infinitely small steps, providing the most accurate possible measure for the path description given.

Before getting into an answer, I shall first address a question in one of the comments. The question was `But can you explain to me that if displacement is $0$
then how displacement can have direction?'
To answer this, it is best to consider the mathematical concept of a vector space. The axioms of a vector space guarantee the existence of a special vector called the zero vector. One could think of this as being the one special vector that does not have a direction! So the definition of a vector as being `a quantity that has direction' is not really the proper concept of a vector - it is simply something that one is taught during the early stages of learning. To really understand what a vector is one needs to look at the axioms of a vector space.
Returning back to the original question - you could think of the concept of distance as always related to a particular path - it is the 'arc length' of the path in question. In other words, think of distance as the length that a piece of string would need to be if it was laid along the path.
The concept of displacement, by way of contrast, has nothing to do with a path. A vector is produced connecting the two endpoints. All of these concepts are treated more properly by the mathematical concept of an affine space.
The space in which we live and move is not properly modelled by a vector space. The reason is that whilst the vector space axioms allow us to add two vectors, it makes no sense whatsoever to write
Paris + Mumbai = ?
Furthermore we can multiply vectors by a scalar but it makes no sense to write
3 $\times$ New Delhi.
Because of this, physical space is better modelled by the concept of an affine space.

See the First and Second Geodetic Problems: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesy Latitude, Longitude, Height above Ellipsoid aka $(\phi, \lambda, h)$ is one of my favorite affine spaces, and no: lat/lon are NOT angles. They are geodetic coordinates measured in degrees, and whenever I ever see them in radians, I lose it.
